# Adding an image into a ToggleButtonGroup

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

I want to implement this design:

[image: photo]

And I'm currently kind of stuck at the images-answers part.

I have the idea, but there is a problem.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { ToggleButtonGroup, ToggleButton } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './css/GameAnswers.css';
import GameImage from './GameImage';

type GameAnswersProps = {
    arrayAnswers: Array<string>,
    arrayAnswersImages?: Array<string>,
    correctAnswer: string,
    setFinishedGameHandler: Function
}

function GameAnswers(props: GameAnswersProps) {
    const [selectedAnswer, setSelectedAnswer] = useState("");

    const handleAnswerChange = function (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
        setSelectedAnswer(e.target.value);
    }

    const determineButtonVariant = function (answer: string) {
        if (answer !== selectedAnswer) {
            return "primary";
        } else if (answer === props.correctAnswer) {
            props.setFinishedGameHandler(true);
            return "success";
        } else {
            props.setFinishedGameHandler(false);
            return "danger";
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="game-answers">
            {
                props.arrayAnswersImages === undefined ?
                    <GameImage className="game-details-image" images={[{ imgSrc: "/Untitled.png", imgAlt: 'test' }]} /> :
                    ""
            }
            <ToggleButtonGroup type="radio" name="answers">
                {props.arrayAnswers.map(function (answer, index) {
                    return <div>
                        {props.arrayAnswersImages !== undefined ?
                            <GameImage className="game-togglebutton" images={[{ imgSrc: props.arrayAnswersImages[index], imgAlt: 'test' }]} /> : ""
                        }
                        <ToggleButton
                            id={answer}
                            value={answer}
                            onChange={handleAnswerChange}
                            variant={determineButtonVariant(answer)}
                        >{answer}</ToggleButton>
                    </div>
                })}
            </ToggleButtonGroup>
        </div>
    );
}

export default GameAnswers;
```

Because the map function returns a div, my ToggleButton doesn't work properly. If I will click on the buttons, nothing will happen.

If I remove the div wrapping, I will get an error because I return two components.

If I also remove the GameImage component, everything will work fine, but I will have no image above the text.

So, how can I make my code work properly while I still have the image above the ToggleButton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react you can use [Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html), it's a common way to exclude that extra node when 
 e.g. returing a list.

Change your wrapping `<div></div>` tag into ->
`<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>`.

A shorter syntax for this is `<></>`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't know that.